# ReactApp - The browser does not refresh the page when i save changes in my js file in VS code editor .

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

What is that thing we need to install that automatically reloads the browser page when we save something in our editor .

Comment: use `create-react-app`

Comment: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader)